# Hypothetical sources of partition function of a quantum theory of gravity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, partition-function

Let's assume there exists a partition function $Z[J_i]$ for a theory of quantum gravity, with a family of sources $(J_i)_i$. Given the Palatini action in 3+1 dimensions:
\begin{equation}
S_P[e,\omega]=-\beta \int d^4 x\,e\,e^\mu_I e^\nu_J \Omega^{IJ}_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
(with $\Omega=d_\omega \omega=d\omega+\omega\wedge_{\mathfrak{spin}(1,3)}\omega$), we see that there are two types of information mixed in it. On one hand one has the information of the relativistic effects, and the other the information of the curvature (since they are decoupled in the Palatini action). Are the sources of this hypothetical partition function related to these two types of parameters? And is this action considered to be an interactive action between these two types of information (due to the $\mathfrak{spin}(1,3)$ wedge product)?